# Best way to use Jasmine to test Angular Controller calls to Services with Promise return

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, jasmine, promise

After a week looking for a good answer/sample, I decided to post my question.

I need to know how is the best way to code and test something like this:

Controller

```
// my.controller.js
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp.myModule').controller('Awesome', Awesome);

  function Awesome($http, $state, AwesomeService) {

    var vm = this; // using 'controllerAs' style

    vm.init = init;
    vm.awesomeThingToDo = awesomeThingToDo;

    vm.init();

    function awesomeThingToDo() {
      AwesomeService.awesomeThingToDo().then(function (data) {
        vm.awesomeMessage = data.awesomeMessage;
      });
    }

    function init() {
        vm.awesomeThingToDo(); // Should be ready on page start
    }
  }
})();
```

Service

```
// my.service.js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp.myModule').factory('AwesomeService', AwesomeService);

  function AwesomeService($resource, $http) {

    var service = {
      awesomeThingToDo: awesomeThingToDo
    }

    return service;

    function awesomeThingToDo() {

      var promise = $http.get("/my-backend/api/awesome").then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });

      return promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

My app works OK with this structure. And my Service unit tests are OK too.
But I don't know how to do unit tests on Controller.

I tried something like this:

Specs

```
// my.controller.spec.js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  describe("Awesome Controller Tests", function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.myModule'));

    var vm, awesomeServiceMock;

    beforeEach(function () {
      awesomeServiceMock = { Is this a good (or the best) way to mock the service?
        awesomeThingToDo: function() {
          return {
            then: function() {}
          }
        }
      };
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
      vm = $controller('Awesome', {AwesomeService : awesomeServiceMock});
    }));

    it("Should return an awesome message", function () {
      // I don't know another way do to it... :(
      spyOn(awesomeServiceMock, "awesomeThingToDo").and.callFake(function() {
        return {
          then: function() {
            vm.awesomeMessage = 'It is awesome!'; // <-- I think I shouldn't do this.
          }
        }
      });

      vm.awesomeThingToDo(); // Call to real controller method which should call the mock service method.

      expect(vm.awesomeMessage).toEqual('It is awesome!'); // It works. But ONLY because I wrote the vm.awesomeMessage above.

    });

  });
})();
```

My app uses Angular 1.2.28 and Jasmine 2.1.3 (with Grunt and Karma).

UPDATE: Solved!

```
it("Should return an awesome message", function () {
  // Solved with callback parameter
  spyOn(awesomeServiceMock, "awesomeThingToDo").and.callFake(function(callback) {
    return {
      then: function(callback) {
        callback({awesomeMessage: 'It is awesome!'}); //callback call works fine! :D
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not how I would do this.

First, there is no need to create a mock service: you can inject the real one, and spy on it.

Second, Angular has everything you need to create promises and to resolve them. No need to create fake objects with a fake `then()` function.

Here's how I would do it:

```
describe("Awesome Controller Tests", function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.myModule'));

    var vm, awesomeService, $q, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _awesomeService_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
      $q = _$q_;
      awesomeService = _awesomeService_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      vm = $controller('Awesome');
    }));

    it("Should return an awesome message", function () {
      spyOn(awesomeService, "awesomeThingToDo").and.returnValue(
          $q.when({
            awesomeMessage: 'awesome message'
          }));

      vm.awesomeThingToDo(); 

      // at this time, the then() callback hasn't been called yet: 
      // it's called at the next digest loop, that we will trigger

      $rootScope.$apply();

      // now the then() callback should have been called and initialized 
      // the message in the controller with the message of the promise
      // returned by the service

      expect(vm.awesomeMessage).toBe('awesome message');
    });

});
```

Unrelated note: 1.2.28 is quite old. You should migrate to the latest version.

Comment: I would update the Angular version... But I can't do it for now. :(
But I updated the question with the solution. :D
Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is both too verbose, and not optimal: the promise is supposed to be asynchronous, but your test makes it synchronous. You should prefer the promise-based solution explained in my answer.

Comment: You're right. My solution isn't good enough.

I tried to apply your solution, injecting the Service, using $q... but I received this error:
Error: Unexpected request: GET /my-backend/api/awesome

Comment: That means that either you haven't spied on the service method, or the service method was called before you spied on it. If what you posted is the real code, and you have used my testing code as is, I don't see how this could happen. If not, then post the actual code you tried.

Comment: This is only a sample code. The real code has a little difference: some controller methods are called on `init()`. And some of these methods call services methods. 
Question updated again. ;)

Comment: init(), in the code you posted, is just another function. My guess is that, in your real code, init() is called from the controller constructor, i.e. when it's instantiated. If that's the case, then you need to spy on the service methods **before** inistantiating the controller. If you spy after, it's too late.

Comment: Sorry, sorry... `init()` is called from constructor (question updated again). This is the reason of mocked service.

Comment: No need to mock the service. spy on the real, injected service, then instantiate yous controller. The controller will received the service you spied on.

Comment: So... I tried to inject the real service, but...

1) how can I use the real service avoiding the `Error: Unexpected request: GET /my-backend/api/awesome` **(without previous spy)** and `jasmine already been spied upon` **(with spy before controller instantiation)**?

2) The controller `unit` tests should not avoid use service real instances?

Comment: **Move** the line `spyOn(...)` before the line `vm = $controller('Awesome');`, since it's when instantiating the controller that the service is called.

Comment: I tried it too. But my controller is instantiated on beforeEach(). If I put a generic spy on beforeEach, the Jasmine throws `jasmine already been spied upon` when I call another spy. And about this question: **he controller unit tests should not avoid use service real instances?**

Comment: Don't spy again in your it() method. Or create your controller in the it() method. You're not using the real service, since you spy on it and replace the real implementation by a fake one.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the question with a possible (bad) solution:

```
it("Should return an awesome message", function () {
  // Solved with callback parameter
  spyOn(awesomeServiceMock, "awesomeThingToDo").and.callFake(function(callback) {
    return {
      then: function(callback) {
        callback({awesomeMessage: 'It is awesome!'}); //callback call works fine! :D
      }
    }
  });
```

I used a callback to pass the mocked parameter and call the real implementation. :D